# how to use riverpod future inside my stateless widget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to use my productsrepository request here, but I'm not sure about the code generated by GPT, I just want to test my fetchProductsList function.
Also
**fake_products_repository.dart:**

```
class ProductsRepository {
  Future<http.Response> fetchProductsList() async {
    final url =
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:80/ecommerceflutter/items/items.php');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    // return Future.value(_products.value);
    return Future.value(response);
  }
}

final productsRepositoryProvider = Provider<ProductsRepository>((ref) { //by chatGPT
  // You can initialize your repository here if needed
  return ProductsRepository();
});

final productsListProvider = FutureProvider<http.Response>((ref) async { //by chatGPT
  final repository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  final response = await repository.fetchProductsList();
  return response;
});
```

product_grid.dart

```
tsGrid extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productsListValue = ref.watch(productsListProvider); //  Undefined name 'productsListProvider'.⏎Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

    return productsListValue.when(
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error $err'),
      data: (products) => ProductsLayoutGrid,
    );
  }
}

class ProductsLayoutGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsLayoutGrid(
      {super.key, required this.itemCount, required this.itemBuilder});
  final int itemCount;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int) itemBuilder;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) itemBuilder(context, i),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

how can I use it inside my consumer widget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you imported `productsListProvider`